# Computer software - adaptor

Tags: windows-8

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop. I accidentally uninstalled qualcomm atheros AR8172 - Fast Ethernet program. I cannot now connect and download the driver. Any ideas how I can obtain the program please?
I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you tried toshiba's site? They ought to have the right driver for your laptop

Comment: Are you sure you really deleted the driver?  Try going to Windows key + R -> Run -> devmgmt.msc -> then right click the PC at the top of that list, then Scan for Hardware changes.  It may reload the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Go to another computer with Internet Access, download the driver from the link below, save it in an USB Stick. Install the driver in your machine using the program saved on the USB Stick.

Link: http://www.driverscape.com/download/qualcomm-atheros-ar8172-8176-8178-pci-e-fast-ethernet-controller

I hope it help you.